# Is there a way to share high quality page screenshot on Facebook when sharing the page URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I ran into a scenario where i need to share the high quality screen shot when sharing the URL of the page that will be shared using FB.ui({...}) fb sdk method.

I am open for any suggestion or approach which can be used to achieve the solution. The page is developed in ASP.NET MVC, HTML5 and Bootstrap.

I can also generate the page screenshots using console application on server side, but i need a way to generate screenshot using browser engine that supports the HTML5 and rendering high quality screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the image facebook shows on the shared link by defining an Open graph object on the page.

Here's some documentation from Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object

(Specially look for the Image section)

And here are some Facebook best practices for image size: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: Actually the page content is dynamic, and changing as per activity of a user, so before assigning the <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/logo.jpg">, i need to generate the screenshot before hand, so that FB can pick that image.

Comment: My situation is very similar to yours, Ronak. I take it you found no solution to your problem?